# wwwless site using url rewrite iis 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to remove www. from a site, so I write a small code on my base page.

```
    if (Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("www.example.com") > -1)
    {
        Response.RedirectPermanent(Request.Url.ToString().Replace("www.example.com", "example.com"), true);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

This works, but on an SSL page, browser gives certificate error because my certificate is signed to **example.com**

So I think I need to use **URL Rewrite module** in IIS 8.5 and tried this.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="remove www." stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www\.)(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This fails, because it redirects www.example.com to www.example.com/example.com

Please help me writing a rewriter which redirects properly. Thank you.

**Edit:**

I succeeded redirecting http pages but still failing https redirect getting **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. I wrote 2 rules

```
            <rule name="remove www. (https)" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="remove www. (http)" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

I am totally lost here. Why does not first rule work but the second does?

**2nd edit:**

Actually that rules are **working** for both http and https. `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` happens because of https bindings lost. But I am still getting certificate error.

I seams, browsers do not check redirects and stop execution of page incase of a certificate error.

Comment: You might not want a non-www domain http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-dub-dub-dub-debate/ and https://brunolm.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/routing-non-www-to-www-domain-and-vice-versa-using-iis-url-rewrite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting www to non-www

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www[.](.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}"
          redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Converting non-www to www *make sure to update domain suffix

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+[.]com)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}"
          redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```